# Trying to figure out the basics of Android Internal Databases

Tags: android, database, internal

I'm a newbie at App Development, Android, and Internal Databases in general.  I need to code a simple database filled with strings and display the strings at the push of a button on the screen for a demonstration. The most important part of the demonstration is the Internal Database. I can't seem to find a good tutorial on how to write one for an Android App. Can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried google?  search results for "android sqlite tutorial" seem to be pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need a database adapter with a databse helper. The adapter will process your datase access and the helper will process open, create, and upgrade. Here is an article from Code Project:

[Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android)

Here's an example of using a database adapter and helper:

```
public void loadList() {
    String title = "";
    arrayAdapter.clear();
    DaysDatabaseAdapter dbAdapter = new DaysDatabaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    dbAdapter.open();
    Cursor c = dbAdapter.getAllRows();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            title = c.getString(DaysDatabaseAdapter.POS_TITLE);
            arrayAdapter.add(title);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
    dbAdapter.close();
}
```

Below is a database adapter from one of my projects. It's and old one and I have better techniques now, but it works.

public class DaysDatabaseAdapter {

// Globals

```
public static final String TAG = "DaysDBAdapter";

public static final String COLUMN_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_INUSE = "inuse";
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
public static final String COLUMN_YEAR = "year";
public static final String COLUMN_MONTH = "month";
public static final String COLUMN_DAY = "day";
public static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = {
    COLUMN_ROWID, COLUMN_INUSE, COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_YEAR, COLUMN_MONTH, COLUMN_DAY
};
public static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES_NO_ROWID = {
    COLUMN_INUSE, COLUMN_TITLE, COLUMN_YEAR, COLUMN_MONTH, COLUMN_DAY
};

public static final int POS_ROWID = 0;
public static final int POS_INUSE = 1;
public static final int POS_TITLE = 2;
public static final int POS_YEAR = 3;
public static final int POS_MONTH = 4;
public static final int POS_DAY = 5;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "daystildayssince";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "days";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE
        + " (" 
        + COLUMN_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_INUSE + " integer not null, "
        + COLUMN_TITLE + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_YEAR + " integer not null, "
        + COLUMN_MONTH + " integer not null, "
        + COLUMN_DAY + " integer not null"
        + ");";

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

// ******************* Functions ***************************

// Constructor

public DaysDatabaseAdapter(Context ctx) {
    MyLog.d(TAG, "Adapter Constructor entered");
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
}

// Open the database

public DaysDatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    MyLog.d(TAG, "open database");
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Close the database

public void close() {
    MyLog.d(TAG, "close database");
    DBHelper.close();
}

// Insert row

public long insertRow(int inuse, String title, int year, int month, int day) {
    MyLog.d(TAG, "insertRow");
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_INUSE, inuse);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_YEAR, year);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_MONTH, month);
    initialValues.put(COLUMN_DAY, day);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// Delete row using COLUMN_ROWID

public boolean deleteRow(long rowid) {
    MyLog.d(TAG, "delete row " + Long.toString(rowid));
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, COLUMN_ROWID + " = " + Long.toString(rowid), null) > 0;
}

// Get all rows

public Cursor getAllRows() {
    MyLog.d(TAG, "getAllRows");
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, COLUMN_NAMES, null, null, null, null, null);
}

// Get specific row using COLUMN_ROWID (primary key)

public Cursor getRowByKey(long rowid) throws SQLException {
    MyLog.d(TAG, "getRowByKey");
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, COLUMN_NAMES, COLUMN_ROWID + " = " + Long.toString(rowid), null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

// Get all rows that match COLUMN_INUSE (the Widget AppWidgetId used for the match.)

public Cursor getInuseMatches(int appWidgetId) throws SQLException {
    MyLog.d(TAG, "getInuseMatches");
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
            COLUMN_NAMES, COLUMN_INUSE + " = " + Integer.toString(appWidgetId),
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

// Get row(s) that match title

public Cursor getTitleMatches(String title) throws SQLException {
    MyLog.d(TAG, "TitleMatches");
    String where[] = {title};
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,
            COLUMN_NAMES, COLUMN_TITLE + " = ?",
            where, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

// Turn off COLUMN_INUSE in matching rows

public boolean setUnused(int inuse) {
    MyLog.d(TAG, "Adapter setUnused");
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_INUSE, 0);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, contentValues, COLUMN_INUSE + " = " + Integer.toString(inuse), null) > 0;
}

// Turn off COLUMN_INUSE in all rows

public boolean setAllUnused() {
    MyLog.d(TAG, "Adapter setAllUnused");
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_INUSE, 0);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, contentValues, null, null) > 0;
}

// Set COLUMN_INUSE to Widget id using COLUMN_ROWID (primary key)

public boolean setInuse(long rowid, int inuse) {
    MyLog.d(TAG, "setInuse (" + Long.toString(rowid) + ", " + Integer.toString(inuse) + ")");
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_INUSE, inuse);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, contentValues, COLUMN_ROWID + " = " + Long.toString(rowid), null) > 0;
}

// ***************** inline classes ***********************

// Database Helper Class

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String TAG = "DaysDBHelper";

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        MyLog.d(TAG, "Constructor");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        MyLog.d(TAG, "Helper onCreate entered");
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        MyLog.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: By the way, SQLite is used on servers with PHP, and in windows. I converted a database from Access to SQLite on my PC. I download the database and process it on Andoid phones. In other words, you can learn all about SQLite on your PC and use that knowlege to write Android apps that process SQLite databases. For your PC get SQLiteSpy to play with. Then use what you've learned on Androids.